# QML, How to correctly expose c++ type - got "undefined symbol"

Tags: qt, qml, qmetatype

I have a class that returns a list of custom objescts, to view in qml

```
#include <QObject>
#include "networkinterface.h"

class Network : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Network(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE QList<NetworkInterface> getNetworkAdaptors();

private:
    QList<NetworkInterface> networkAdaptors; };
```

At main.qml i call this method as

```
model: network.getNetworkAdaptors()
```

It all was working when NetworkInterface was a struct, but when i converted it to a class, can't make it work.

Class NetworkInterface is inherited from QObject and got properties

```
class NetworkInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    NetworkInterface();

    QString name;
    QString description;

    const QString &getName() const;
    void setName(const QString &newName);

    const QString &getDescription() const;
    void setDescription(const QString &newDescription);

...
private:
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString description READ getDescription CONSTANT)
};
```

So the error i got is :

```
main.cpp.o:-1: error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "NetworkInterface::NetworkInterface()", referenced from:
      QtPrivate::QMetaTypeForType<NetworkInterface>::getDefaultCtr()::'lambda'(QtPrivate::QMetaTypeInterface const*, void*)::operator()(QtPrivate::QMetaTypeInterface const*, void*) const in mocs_compilation.cpp.o
      Network::getNetworkAdaptors() in network.cpp.o
      _main in main.cpp.o
```

I suspect it is wrong type expose, as with sctruct it was working fine, how to do that correctly?

UPD: in NetworkInterface i have following constructors:

```
 NetworkInterface();

    NetworkInterface(const NetworkInterface &obj);
    NetworkInterface & operator=( const NetworkInterface & obj);
```

Without them i can't push_back(networkInterface) to the list of interfaces, as it requires copy constructor. Also list of pointers won't work for qml as a model, it must be exactly objects list.

When i copy all code in NetworkInterface and leave only above constructors, it is minimal code that gives a error.

Comment: Did you implement your NetworkInterface() ctor somewhere and compile this source?

Comment: @chehrlic
No,  Still got the same error after commenting all networkInterface methods, only copy consctuctor and operator= are left, without them getting error that they are required (by qml i suspect) 
Can copy constructor or = implicitly call for ctor?

Comment: @chehrlic i have added update aboyt copy constructor to the question

Comment: Thanks for you comment, eventually i got what's missing ))

Comment: To return a list of QObject it is complicated. Either as QObject pointers, or use QGadgets, or via a QQmlListProperty. Each solution requires some thought to the object ownership and life cycle of the information given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default constructor was missing, adding

```
NetworkInterface::NetworkInterface(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
```

Resoled a problem

Comment: Yes, you actually had the correct constructor for `Network`, you were missing it for `NetworkInterface`. Just as a clarification, it's preferred to use `nullptr` instead of `0`, i.e. `QNetworkInterface(QObject* parent = nullptr);`. Because your method returns `QList<NetworkInterface>` unfortunately that means additional copy construction occurring. When you get deeper into the lifecycle of your objects, you may have fine-grain control over construction/destruction and may want to consider changing to a pointer, e.g. `QList<NetworkInterface*>`.

Comment: @StephenQuan thanks a lot! Exactly what you say - did happen, i came to list of pointer eventually.